# Select From Multiple and New Tables will be created

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Simple Query is

```
SELECT MAX(DATETIME)
FROM gss.dbo.contacts_23
WHERE Identification = ''
GROUP BY Identification
```

How can I select `Max(date)` from 25 tables and new tables can be created?

These tables like `(contacts_22,contacts_25,contacts_29,contacts_36,..  and the new)`

I tried to think as following

- use union but what about the new tables will be created next time
- select all tables start with 'contacts_' to fetch all these tables and the tables will be created next time

```
    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
        FROM GSS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME like 'contacts_%'
```

but it's not doable with `FROM` clause

How can I do that GET `MAX(DATE) FROM ....` AND NEW TABLES

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your primary effort should go into fixing your data model. These N tables should really be just one table.

Comment: I think that too, it's not my work but I will send ur msg

Answer (score 0):

The data model is horrible, and there is no clean way of achieving what you want.

The first way is to create a view which unions all your `contacts_` tables, and then to run your query on that view.

```
Create view contacts_view as
select * from contacts_20
union
select * from contacts_21
...
```

This is the simplest solution, but only works if you can be certain that you're not creating more tables which need to be included in the view.

The alternative is to use [dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/.). This would use your query on the schema database to construct a SQL statement, which you then execute. This can get moderately complex, and is generally hard to test and debug, but does allow new tables to be automatically included in the results.